# How to UI test if an attributed string is crossed out or not

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing

I am using this method to cross out a string

```swift
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your Text")
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))

yourLabel.attributedText = attributeString
```

now, I am creating a UI test to test a label. I want to check if the label is crossed out (Strikethrough) or not.

How can I do that?

This is the UI test code

```swift
let mastertableviewTable = app.tables["masterTableview"]
let staticText = mastertableviewTable.staticTexts["task two"]
```

Comment: Use a unit test, not a UI test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only answer to this, is I shouldn't UI test how content looks like, but I should test if the specific content is available of not.
as there is no way in UI testing we can get objects attributes, like color, font size ...

Answer (score 0):

You shall probably use screen snapshot comparison tool like

https://github.com/uber/ios-snapshot-test-case

It is pretty simple to install. Though tool I mentioned is designed to be used in unit testing it also runs perfectly in UI tests targets.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [`attribute(attrName:location:range:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1408174-attribute).

```swift
var range: NSRange
var attributedText: NSAttributedString

...

if attributedText.attribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, at: attributedText.length - 1, effectiveRange: &range) != nil {
    // OK!
} else {
    // Not OK!
}
```

Comment: In a UI test? How?